# Neo4j Cypher how to include another relationship node of parent in APOC neo4j cypher query

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc

Let us considered

- Drone (Parent)

  - Quadcropter (Child)

    - Pixel (Grand Child)

with [:SUB_CATEGORY] as relationship node
[image]

below Cypher query to fetch along with its parts tagged with each nodes

```
MATCH p=(n:Category)-[:SUB_CATEGORY*]->(m)<-[:TAGGED_TO]-(part:Part)
WHERE NOT ()-[:SUB_CATEGORY]->(n) AND toLower(part.name) STARTS WITH toLower('atm')
WITH COLLECT(p) AS ps
RETURN ps
```

above cypher query returns actual result set i.e., its showing all relationship both SUB_CATEGORY and TAGGED_TO

[image]

Now if I used to convert this into Tree structure using APOC procedure then it skip TAGGED_TO relationship node of Parent Node i.e., Drone

```
MATCH p=(n:Category)-[:SUB_CATEGORY*]->(m)<-[:TAGGED_TO]-(part:Part)
WHERE NOT ()-[:SUB_CATEGORY]->(n) AND toLower(part.name) STARTS WITH toLower('atm')
WITH COLLECT(p) AS ps
CALL apoc.convert.toTree(ps) YIELD value
RETURN value
```

Can you give me suggestion for getting the TAGGED_TO node of all nodes along with parent node using APOC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first query, the `TAGGED_TO` relationship between the parent node `Drone` and the `:Part` node is shown because the browser option `Connect result nodes` is enabled:

> If this is checked, after a cypher query result is retrieved, a second
>   query is executed to fetch relationships between result nodes.

But in fact in the result there is no such relationship because match pattern does not take into account the possibility of [a path with a long zero](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/patterns/#cypher-pattern-varlength). Try this:

```
MATCH p=(n:Category)-[:SUB_CATEGORY*0..]->(m:Category)<-[:TAGGED_TO]-(part:Part)
WHERE NOT ()-[:SUB_CATEGORY]->(n) AND toLower(part.name) STARTS WITH toLower('atm')
WITH COLLECT(p) AS ps
CALL apoc.convert.toTree(ps) YIELD value
RETURN value
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried your suggestion but still couldn't get any result for above query. same result it doesn't include TAGGED_TO relation node with root node 'DRONE'